# How to use prototype with require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I have below code that I want to import in Node modules:

```
Kc.prototype.middleware = function(options) {

  options.logout = options.logout || '/logout';
  options.admin  = options.admin  || '/';

  var middlewares = [];

  middlewares.push( Setup );
  middlewares.push( PostAuth(this) );
  middlewares.push( AdminLogout(this, options.admin) );
  middlewares.push( GrantAttacher(this) );
  middlewares.push( Logout(this, options.logout) );

  return middlewares;
};
```

I'm requiring this in my main.js:

```
var kc = require('connect-kc');

server.use(kc.middleware());
```

But I'm getting `has no method 'middleware'` error

What can I do to require and use middleware in my main.js?

I'm using [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) framework.

Comment: On a side note, don't use push for static arrays, the array literal syntax is much nicer. `[Setup, PostAuth(this), ...]` and to answer your question we would have to see the exports of the connect-kc module.

Comment: What is `Kc`? How/what do you export in that `connect-kc` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm getting `has no method 'middleware'` error

That's because your `Kc` object doesn't have a `middleware` property. It has a `prototype` property that has `middleware`.

If `Kc` is a function, you probably wanted to use it like this:

```
var Kc = require('connect-kc');

var kc = new Kc();
server.use(kc.middleware());
```

If `Kc` *isn't* a function, then:

```
var Kc = require('connect-kc');

server.use(Kc.prototype.middleware());
```

...but I would **strongly** recommend you not give it a property called `prototype`, as that's very misleading. The `prototype` property on function instances references the object that that function will assign to instances when instances are created by `new TheFunctionName`.

---

Side note 1:

This code is suspect:

```
options.logout = options.logout || '/logout';
options.admin  = options.admin  || '/';
```

It's generally not a good idea to reach out and change the caller's object like that. Instead, typically it's useful to have a function around that copies properties between instances (it's frequently called `extend`), and then:

```
var opts = extend({}, defaults, options);
```

...where `defaults` has those default `logout` and `admin` options. Then use `opts` rather than `options`. The `extend` function looks something vaguely like this:

```
function extend(target) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function(arg) {
        Object.keys(arg).forEach(function(key) {
            target[key] = arg[key];
        });
    });
    return target;
}
```

---

Side note 2:

You can create the `middlewares` array much more succinctly and *(subjectively)* clearly if you like:

```
var middlewares = [
  Setup,
  PostAuth(this),
  AdminLogout(this, options.admin),
  GrantAttacher(this),
  Logout(this, options.logout)
];
```

Comment: How can I change it so I can use `middleware` without instantiating it and just use `require`?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper: Put `middleware` right on your `Kc` object, rather than on an object referenced from a property called `prototype`.

Comment: Great it works thank you.
I'm also getting `  options.logout = options.logout || '/logout';
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined`
I thought this is optional but apparently it works when I omit `()` in `server.use(Kc.middleware)`